# I...Handler that triggers when the input is stationary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, interface, event-handling

I am creating a virtual joystick, i implement `IDragHandler` to detect dragging motion:

```
public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
    Vector2 target;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle (borderRect, eventData.position, Camera.main, out target);
    float radius = borderRect.rect.width / 2;
    float tilt = target.magnitude / radius;
    Vector2 direction = target.normalized;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (direction.x, direction.y);
    if (tilt > 1) {
        target = new Vector2 (radius * Mathf.Sin (angle), radius * Mathf.Cos (angle));
        tilt = 1;
    }
    angle *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    if (angle < 0f) angle += 360f;
    stickRect.anchoredPosition = target;
    if (onJoystickDrag != null) {
        onJoystickDrag (tilt, direction, angle);
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly. But when the user stops dragging while holding down the joystick the method is not called anymore. A subscriber, say the player controller is only recieving direction when the joystick is moving. The player controller should also get these variables when the joystick is held down and stationary.

I need to override some method that is called continuousely when the joystick is held down and stationary. What is some good I...Handler for this?
I was looking for a`IPointerStationaryHandler` or similar but i couldn't find anything.

To clarify, i am looking for some specialized I...Handler interface that is triggered continuousely when the input position is stationary.

Comment: IPointerDownHandler with a check to make sure it's not dragging might do the trick for you

Comment: @ryeMoss IPointerDownHandler is only triggered the first frame. I need something that triggers continuousely, like IDragHandler.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html): Detects ongoing mouse clicks until release of the mouse button. So I guess that is kind of vague to me. Give it a shot and see what happens maybe?

Comment: @ryeMoss I ran the script in the link and it only prints once :(

Comment: Well in that case, you could alternatively set a bool true when clicking begins, and set to false when mouse is released. and check to make sure it is not being dragged during

Comment: @ryeMoss yeah i guess that is my only option for now ...

Comment: Alternative to that alternative would be to use [Input.GetMouseButton(0)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) if that's an option for you

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @Programmer nope, i ditched all the i...Handler interfaces and wrote my joystick using Touch and the Touchphase enum which allows you to detect stationary touches.

Comment: What a waste. You could have done this with a simple timer that activates when IDragHandler is not called for x seconds. When `IDragHandler` is not called for x secsonds, set a boolean variable to true then check this variable in the Update function. It's not really hard

Comment: @Programmer I don't know about waste. My reasoning was that if the IHandler interfaces did not support all the functionality i needed it was better to use something that did. I think setting and querying booleans like that is not that hard yes, but personally i find it ugly.

Comment: What I mean mean by waste is discarding your original code and spending time writing a new one  that will only work on mobile devices. There is when the `Input` class should be used but the eventsystem is better here because this feature can be easily implemented with it an it will work on both desktop and mobile devices too. It's ok. You can use anything that works for you

Comment: @Programmer That is true. I'ts a joystick so it won't be used on any other platform. But i suppose it would be nice to be able to test it without needing to hook up my phone to the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ditched all the i...Handler interfaces and wrote my joystick using Touch and the Touchphase enum which allows you to detect stationary touches.

This does not really answer my question but since what i am looking for does not even exist in i will accept this answer.